# Access object value with computed property keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am writing a little helper which is supposed to get the min Item of an array.

The function takes an `Array` as first param and the "path" to access the object property 'rest' parameters.

Ex: `minItem(stops, 'duration', 'total');`

console.log: `// [object object][duration][total]`

Expected: `// Number, Which is the value of total`

```js
const stops = 
[{"transport":"train","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid","duration":
{"h":"03","m":"15","total":195},"cost":160,"discount":0,
"reference":"TPM0315","initialPrice":160},
{"transport":"bus","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid",
"duration":{"h":"06","m":"45","total":405},"cost":30,"discount":25,
"reference":"BPM0645","initialPrice":40},
{"transport":"car","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid","duration":
{"h":"05","m":"45","total":345},"cost":120,"discount":0,
"reference":"CPM0545","initialPrice":120}];


/** @function minItem */
const minItem = (array, ...args) => {
  const keys = `['${[...args].join('\'][\'')}']`;
  array.reduce((a, b) => {
    console.log(b + keys);
    return a + keys <= b + keys ? a : b;
  }, {});
};

minItem(stops, 'duration', 'total');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the minimum values by using [Math#min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) on an array of minimum values, created using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). To get the value at the `args` path, you can iterate the keys with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const stops = [{"transport":"train","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid","duration":{"h":"03","m":"15","total":195},"cost":160,"discount":0,"reference":"TPM0315","initialPrice":160},{"transport":"bus","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid","duration":{"h":"06","m":"45","total":405},"cost":30,"discount":25,"reference":"BPM0645","initialPrice":40},{"transport":"car","departure":"Paris","arrival":"Madrid","duration":{"h":"05","m":"45","total":345},"cost":120,"discount":0,"reference":"CPM0545","initialPrice":120}];


/** @function minItem */
const getPathValue = (src, path) => path.reduce((p, k) => typeof p === 'object' ? p[k] : p, src);

const minItem = (array, ...args) => Math.min(...array.map((o) => getPathValue(o, args)));

console.log(minItem(stops, 'duration', 'total'));
```